# htaccess all domains with https/http to one domain using https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I want it so all http or https requests go to https:// mydomain.com using the same page.

So even https:// mydomain.net/donate/ and http:// mydomain.net/donate/ would go to https:// mydomain.com/donate/

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe that I forgot how to do this with htaccess :p

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain/$1 [R,L]
```

That's it.